# Java classes in JMeter with Beanshell sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have a Java project that I need to run as a load test in JMeter. Found some examples that indicated you could make a jar file and put it in the Jmeter lib/ext folder and run it. Works for the simple example program I wrote.

Tried to scale up, made a jar of my larger project, placed it in the lib/ext folder, did the following in Beanshell sampler following the example program.

```
import package.JHelper;
JHelper x = new JHelper();
x.test();
```

I have also tried to import the class using the full path of

```
import cast.sa.vsp.package.JHelper;
import cast.sa.vsp.package.*;
```

Both return me the following response code

```
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking  bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import cast.sa.vsp.package.JHelper; JHelper x = new JHelper();  . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JHelper not found in namespace
```

The only answer I have seen is that it would work if I moved it from /lib/ext to /lib. I have done this as well, with Jmeter being unable to run until I remove the jar from that directory.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this working?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1):

1. Your jars should go to /lib folder (instead of /lib/ext)
2. JMeter restart is absolutely required to pick the jars up
3. It is [not very recommended to use Beanshell for creating actual load](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using "groovy" as a language instead.

For details on JSR223 Sampler performance, instructions on how to install groovy scripting engine and performance benchmarks see [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article.

Comment: Why does placing the jar in the /lib directory keep jmeter from running?

Comment: What does *jmeter.log* say? It shouldn't unless there is a conflict with your jar contents and libraries JMeter relies on